# Convert video from 9:16 to 1:1 with blurred box using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

The Original video resolution is 720:1280 and I want to:

1. copy the original video, scale to 1080:1080 and blur.
2. again copy the original video and scale to 608:1080.
3. Finally move blurred to 1080:1080 box and move second(608:1080) scaled copy above the blurred copy.

**Structure**:

```
Box(1080:1080)
  Blurred(Original -> 1080:1080 -> Blur)
  Scaled(Original -> 608:1080)
```

`ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i tmpVideo.mp4 -vf -filter_complex \
"split[main][copy]; \
[main]scale=1080:1080[container]; \
[copy]scale=-1:1080,split[content, copy1]; \
[copy1]gblur=sigma=20[blurred]; \
[container][blurred]overlay=0:0[mix]; \
[mix][content]overlay=W/2:0" \
output.mp4
```

The error I'm getting:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'split[main][copy]; [main]scale=1080:1080[container]; [copy]scale=-1:1080,split[content, copy1]; [copy1]gblur=sigma=20[blurred]; [container][blurred]overlay=0:0[mix]; [mix][content]overlay=W/2:0'
split[main][copy]; [main]scale=1080:1080[container]; [copy]scale=-1:1080,split[content, copy1]; [copy1]gblur=sigma=20[blurred]; [container][blurred]overlay=0:0[mix]; [mix][content]overlay=W/2:0: Invalid argument
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: An edit *and* an upvote!  **;-)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the input to the filtergraph, for example `0:v`. There are other issues though, so this is what works for me:

```
ffmpeg -i VID_20190619_205627.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=1080:1080,setdar=1:1,gblur=sigma=20[bg]; \
[0:v]scale=-1:1080[ov]; \
[bg][ov]overlay=(W-w)/2:0[mix]" \
-map [mix] -r 25 out.mp4 -y
```

- the first chain of the filtergraph scales the input video to 1080 x 1080, forces the display aspect ratio to 1:1 and blurs the video. This is the background (`bg`)
- the second chain takes the input video again and scales it to ? x 1080. This is the video that will be overlaid (`ov`)
- the last chain overlays the scaled video (`ov`) on the blurred background (`bg`), and produced the output (`mix`), which is then chosen as the output with `-map`.

Note that the blurred background is stretched in this way.

Depending on the type of input, you might want to force the frame rate with `-r 25` or similar, and to copy the audio track with `-map 0:a -c:a copy`.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with 5 separated commands:

```
ffmpeg -i tmpVideo.mp4 scale=1080:1080 container.mp4
ffmpeg -i container.mp4 gblur=sigma=20 blurred.mp4
ffmpeg -i tmpVideo.mp4 scale=-1:1080 content.mp4
ffmpeg -i container.mp4 -i blurred.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=0:0" mix.mp4
ffmpeg -i mix.mp4 -i content.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:0" output.mp4
```

Comment: Are you sure that your first 3 commands are correct without something as `-vf`?

Answer (score 0):

Accepted answer works perfectly, I only needed to change the overlay a bit into `overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2[mix]` because the blurry effect appeared at the bottom of the video all the time